# Configure Machine as both Web Server and Router

Tags: networking, 18.04, router

Let me preface by saying I have very little experience on the networking side of things.

**Context:** I have a machine running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (bionic-dev) that hosts a web page on port 8050. This machine also hosts a hotspot, established using:

```
nmcli device wifi hotspot ifname wl1ps0 ssid QuickHotspot band bg channel 6 password "password"
```

Bionic-dev is connected to my local network via ethernet, and I am able to reach the page on 8050 by going to http://bionic-dev:8050/ from a device also connected to my local network.

**Question:** How can I reach the page on 8050 from a device connected to QuickHotspot?

My inclination is to set up port forwarding of some kind, but all the examples I can find route to a machine downstream from the router doing the forwarding. In this case, the router needs to forward to it's own port 8050.

I think the solution involves something with updating iptables, but as I said before networking is fairly unfamiliar to me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ip -a` to find the IP address assigned to wl1ps0.

Make sure the webserver is also listening on this interface: `lsof -i :8050`. If not, update your apache config (probably /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf). Note, if the hotspot was set up after the web server was started you may just need to restart it to get it to listen on wl1ps0 as well: `sudo service apache2 restart`

Then, for systems connected to QuickHotspot use http://:8050/

This is probably easier and safer than turning port forwarding on.

Comment: I'm not using apache, but I did confirm that the server was listening on 8050. What about port forwarding in in this situation is unsafe?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by doing the following:

```
nmcli device disconnect wlp1s0
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F
nmcli device wifi hotspot ifname wlp1s0 ssid QuickHotspot password "password"
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 10.42.0.0 -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8050
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

This disconnects the hotspot, resets the iptables, restarts the hostpot, creates a forwarding rule, and then enables forwarding.
I omitted the arguments to specify the band or channel in the hotspot intentionally (it was causing the command to sometimes hang for some reason). The nmcli command creates some of it's own iptable rules when called, which is why I disconnected and reconnected the hotspot interface.

I then restarted the web server. (For completeness of documentation, it is a perl server using Mojolicious::Lite. The hosted page also makes http requests to other pages on the www.)

I was able to arrive at this solution by using this page:

https://abidmujtaba.blogspot.com/2016/07/ubuntu-create-wifi-hotspot-access-point.html